# SQL Management Studio: "DBISAM Engine Error # 12035 The table 'step_log' is not the correct version'"

Tags: database, postgresql, dbisam, sql-manager

I´m using SQL Management Studio for PostgreSQL to migrate another DB to PostgreSQL. On starting up and closing down the studio i get the error message from above.
It does not affect any of the steps after yet (the actual work i do with the program) and is, in this way, not a problem YET.
But it is very annoying and will bring problems someday for sure...

If you know a solution pls let me know ;)

--edit
Software used: SQL Management Studio for PostgreSQL 1.3.0 (build 46170)

Comment: Are you referring to [EMS SQL Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net/de/products/postgresql/manager) or [EMS SQL Management Studio](http://www.sqlmanager.net/de/products/studio/postgresql)?

Comment: I am referring to SQL Management Studio for PostgreSQL 1.3.0 (build 46170)

Comment: The DBISAM database engine (in SQL Management Studio?) is being used to attempt to open the step_log file. The error results because either the step_log table was created with a different version of the DBISAM engine or the step_log file isn't actually a DBISAM table file.